# Predicate logic with negation "not"

Tags: predicate-logic

I've really confused myself here:
$$
  P(x) = ``\text{x has a tail}"
$$
How would I write:
$$
  ``\text{Not everything has a tail}"
$$

would it:
$$
¬∀x P(x)
$$

be correct?

Comment: It isn't the same thing. The negation is there is something that doesn't have a tail.

Comment: I do not want to negate "Not everything has a tail" I'm confused as to how to write it out.

Comment: That should be $\lnot\forall$, not $\lnot\exists$. (Remember that $\exists$ means "exists.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Everything doesn't have a tail" is not logically equivalent to ""Not everything has a tail."

Use instead $\lnot \forall xP(x)$, or equivalently $\exists x \lnot P(x)$, there is something that doesn't have a tail.

Comment: so this is the way to write out "Not everything has a tail" in proper notation?

Comment: I'm confused as to how you know you have the negate the entire thing and not just the "everything"

Comment: I modified the answer to give you two alternatives. The simplest is $\lnot\forall xP(x)$. Then I gave an equivalent assertion using the existential quantifier. I suspect that one, for no good reason, may be preferred.

Comment: "Not everything" has a certain property means there is something that doesn't have the property.